# JavaFX Issue with always-visible-datepicker

Tags: javafx, datepicker

Iam trying to create a datepicker which is always open(popup).So i got a working code from githhub link https://gist.github.com/flasheater/ba58d5adffa1324e727e.
But my problem is when i implemented this code on my controller class it showing error.So i would like to post my complete code below.

FXMLDocumentController.java

```
  public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
  @FXML
  private AnchorPane bp;
  @Override
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    final DatePicker date_picker = new DatePicker();
    StackPane root=new StackPane(date_picker);
    date_picker.setVisible( false );
    date_picker.setManaged( false );

   final com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerSkin skin = (com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerSkin) date_picker.getSkin();
   root.getChildren().add(skin.getPopupContent()); 
   //added to stackpane.I think above line is having problem
   bp.getChildren().add(root); //added to anchorpane which already designed via scenebuilder
}
}
```

FXMLDocument.fxml(designed via scenebuilder2.0)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <?import java.lang.*?>
 <?import java.util.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

 <AnchorPane fx:id="bp" prefHeight="443.0" prefWidth="563.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="tableviewmodalbaseview.FXMLDocumentController" />
```

And the error as follows

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:323)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)


Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/17398621.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
    file:/C:/Users/aboosidhu/Documents/NetBeansProjects/TableViewModalBaseView/dist/run1705880335/TableViewModalBaseView.jar!/tableviewmodalbaseview/FXMLDocument.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2605)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2583)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2445)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3218)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3179)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3152)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3128)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3108)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3101)
at tableviewmodalbaseview.TableCellFactorySample.start(TableCellFactorySample.java:46)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$54/31372366.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/22256815.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/23180581.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/265996.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/23703675.run(Unknown Source)
... 1 more



 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at tableviewmodalbaseview.FXMLDocumentController.initialize(FXMLDocumentController.java:151)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
... 22 more
```

So can anyone help me to fix the error on my code.Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: `NullPointerException` : Instantiation problem & what is this `date_picker.getProperties().;` (You do not call any method it's an error you can not even compile like this) ?

Comment: Oh iam sorry that was a typing mistake.Now i editted the code.And that was not a reason for the error.The problem is ,it works when i add datepicker skin with new scene and new stage,but i want add it to my existing fxml file that's all.

Comment: What's in the line 151 of your `FXMLDocumentController.java` ?

Comment: root.getChildren().add(skin.getPopupContent());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what exactly you want to achieve but I do not see the interest of using a `Cast` here :

```
final com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerSkin skin = (com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.DatePickerSkin) date_picker.getSkin();
```

why not use an instance directly with your `DatePicker` as argument :

```
final DatePickerSkin skin = new DatePickerSkin(date_picker);
```

Try to import your components correctly, Good luck !

Comment: wow.it worked perfectly.You are right,casting was the problem.Thanks for your effort.